# mono: is there a gtk gui designer like visual studio 2010?

Tags: user-interface, mono, gtk, designer

My computer system consists of VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.04 as the host and Windows7 as the guest.  Ubuntu serves as my every day computer needs while Windows7 serves as my cross-platform testing needs.
I am using MonoDevelop in Ubuntu 12.04 for all my C# needs.  Is there is a GTK GUI designer for Ubuntu 12.04 that has the ability to help guide the alignment of the GTK Widgets like Visual Studio 2010 does for Controls?  I've been really spoiled with Visual Studio GUI designer, I really like the auto snap(or is it called docking?) and alignment guidance features that VS Studio provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't. GTK uses a table concept to design. You can use vertical or horizontal containers, or tables...

But you can't drag and drog and align with a simple gesture.

You should imagine first what design you want and later think what containers can help you to accomplish your design.

Answer (score 1):

From my research, I'm afraid you have the best Linux has to offer for mono development. The best I can find for you is [Stetic GUI Designer](http://monodevelop.com/documentation/stetic_gui_designer). Never used it, but looks promising.

I've always used Eclipse for my C# dev and there is definitely nothing like that in that community. Considering changing now.

Comment: Stetic is the GUI designer for creating Gtk# applications which I believe is MonoDevelop.  Does Eclipse have a GUI designer? If not, what do you use for a GUI designer?

Comment: Good call. Well at least you helped me out. Sorry I didn't return the favor.